# Accessing JSON value without knowing the key

Tags: json, jquery

I have a json structure as shown in the image[image: JSON]. I want to fetch the `extract` value. Normally I would do

```
         $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'test2.php',
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) 
        {     
            console.log(result.query.pages[168387].extract);

        }
    });
```

But the value `168387` is not a constant and is going to change for each request. Can you please tell me how to access the value of EXTRACT in this case?

Comment: uhm.. make your json response more discoverable?! What is in the `normalized` array? Anything there which might help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to loop and check:

```
for (var key in result.query.pages) {
    if (result.query.page[key].hasOwnProperty("extract"))
        console.log(result.query.page[key].extract); //or log the key value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many many options:

If you know the value of the field, and have it in a variable then can't you just change:

```
console.log(result.query.pages[168387].extract
```

To

```
console.log(result.query.pages[variableWithTheAttributeNameInIt].extract
```

If the "Pages" object is actually an array with consistently shaped objects in it, then make it such and let it auto-increment a key for you.  Then it will be natural to loop over it as the array it is.

If it's not a consistent array and you don't have access to any source that will tell you what the attribute name is, then:

- Change the object so that it tells you itself (e.g. add a new field that IS consistent that tells you what the name of the attribute is)
- Change the object so that the attribute name doesn't change.

With a preference for the second option over the first.